# nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... and Error: Cannot find module './models/document'

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

Nodemon is crashing when an express URL is accessed. It isn't always consistent though. Sometimes it works, sometimes node crashes right when the URL is hit retiring no data, and other times I get a response and node crashed immediately after.
[image]